# How to send all value of database to outputstream

Tags: java, sqlite

I hava a SQLiteDatabase object called MyDb . this object can be filled by calling insertLocation method.

```
public boolean insertLocation(String time, double latitude, double longitude) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cV = new ContentValues();
        cV.put("time", time);
        cV.put("latitude", latitude);
        cV.put("longitude", longitude);
        db.insert("location", null, cV);
        return true;
    }
```

Now i want to put all these data to outputstream , how should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Before the return

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file); 
printWriter.println("time=" + time);
printWriter.println("latitude=" +latitude);
printWriter.println("longitude=" + longitude);
```

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send all entries in the database in an outputStream?

I'm trying to find a better way, but this is what I can come up with:

```
public void saveDatabaseAsTextFile() {

    // Get a cursor of the data
    Cursor c = doYourQuery();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput("locations.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            // For each position of the cursor, create a comma
            // delimited string (with a new line char at the end).
            String line;
            do {
                line = "";
                line = line.concat(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("time")) + ",");
                line = line.concat(c.getDouble(c
                        .getColumnIndex("latitude")) + ",");
                line = line.concat(c.getDouble(c
                        .getColumnIndex("longitude")) + "\n");
                // send the string to the OutputStreamWriter
                writer.write(line);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            // close the OutputStreamWriter
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to write to file, throw that string at some other OutputStream.